# ¿Como restringir el acceso a diferentes puntos del sistemas a través de URL?

Tags: php, html, mysql, angulajs

Como puedo hacer para restringir el acceso a diferentes puntos de mi sistema a través de la URL? Es decir, tengo un login, pongo los datos e ingreso al menú, pero si pongo la dirección url del menú directamente (Salteo la validación del usuario), ingreso de igual manera, y así igual con cualquier punto. Como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: En cada página de tu web deberías comprobar si el usuario está logeado. Eso lo puedes hacer con session_start() y recibir la variable de login. En caso de que no estén logeados con un isset(variablequealmacenaellogin) te basta para que no cargue, o, como es un if, que cargue un mensaje de error. Te recomiendo que leas [mcve] y [ask] para aprender como hacer una pregunta adecuada a la que podamos contestar y te sea útil. Un saludo y bienvenido a SOes.

Answer (score -1):

bienvenido a SOes.

De primer instancia me gustaría saber de que manera estás haciendo tu inicio de sesión, es decir, donde almacenas la información del usuario al iniciar sesión? A partir de ahí realizar validaciones dentro de cada controller para verificar que el usuario está loggeado y si no es así lo mande a la página principal. Te doy un ejemplo:

Por lo regular uso de usuario las cookies (solo el usuario) y a traves de permisos del sistema yo le digo al usuario si es admitido o no en la página. Si solo quieres ocupar las cookies te dejo aquí un ejemplo:

```
if (($scope.user_permissions.view_user_birthdates != 1) || ($cookies.get('user') === undefined)) {    
    $location.path('/');
}
```